# Is 1 cm2 = to 3.033ml x 3.033333...ml?

Tags: geometry, area, surfaces, unit-of-measure

Is 1 cm2 = to 3.033Millimeters x 3.033333...ml?

Because length x width = square area.

Or is it 1cm x 1cm.

Or Every time I said a "Square meter, kilometre or centimetre" means:

1cm2 = 1cm x 1cm 1km2 = 1 km x 1 km

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: 1 ml is $10^{-3}$ litres, I suppose.

Comment: $1\ cm^3 = 1\ ml$ -- $cm$ is a unit of length $cm^3$ is a unit of volume and $ml$ is a unit of volume.

Comment: i mean Millimeters

Comment: One $\text{cm}^2$ is the area of a square with side length $1\,\text{cm}$.

Comment: The abbreviation for $\color{'red'}{m}$illi$\color{'red'}{m}$eter(s) is mm, not ml.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you *meant* to ask: is $1 \text{ cm}^2$ equal to $3.033 \text{ mm} \cdot 3.033333 \ldots \text{ mm}$?

The answer is no, because

$$\begin{align}
1 \text{ cm}^2 &= (10 \text{ mm})^2\\
&= 10^2 \text{ mm}^2\\
&= 100 \text{ mm}^2,
\end{align}$$

whereas

$$\begin{align}
3.033 \text{ mm} \cdot 3.033333 \ldots \text{ mm} &= (3.033 \cdot 3.033333 \ldots) \text{ mm}^2\\
&= 9.2001 \text{ mm}^2 \text{ (exactly)}.
\end{align}$$

I'm really curious where you came up with the numbers $3.033$ and $3.033333 \ldots$, and what you expected the product $3.033 \cdot 3.033333 \ldots$ to be...

Comment: i just totally mistaked